# sql error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure. But getting this strange error..
Would be nice if anybody can help me...

this is my stored proc.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_search] (@keyword NVARCHAR(500))
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @tab TABLE (
        id          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        Title       NVARCHAR(250),
        Description NVARCHAR(500),
        FilePath    NVARCHAR(500),
        UploadDate  DATETIME,
        FileName    NVARCHAR(250),
        CourseName  NVARCHAR(150),
        FullName    NVARCHAR(250),
        School      NVARCHAR(250))

      INSERT INTO @tab
      SELECT un.Id,
             un.Title,
             un.Description,
             un.FileName,
             un.FilePath,
             uc.CourseName,
             up.Fullname,
             up.School,
             un.UploadDate
      FROM   UserNotes un
             INNER JOIN UserCourse uc
               ON un.CourseId = uc.Id
             INNER JOIN UserProfile up
               ON up.Id = un.UserId
      WHERE  FREETEXT(( un.Title, un.Description, un.Tag ), @keyword)

      SELECT *
      FROM   @tab

      RETURN
  END 

--exec usp_search 'mvc'
```

this is the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specifying the columns in your select statement in the same order that they are declared in your table.

So either add a columns clause to your insert - e.g.

```
INSERT INTO @tab (ID, Title, Description ...)
```

Or change the order of the columns that you are selecting. It would seem to me that you want

```
SELECT un.Id,
       un.Title,
       un.Description,
       un.FilePath,
       un.UploadDate,
       un.FileName,
       uc.CourseName,
       up.Fullname,
       up.School
...
```

Comment: @kandroid - Why are you bothering with the intermediate table variable at all? It doesn't seem to be needed from the code you have posted and just adds additional overhead (as well as ensuring your `SELECT` can never have a parallel plan)

Comment: well, when I do  'function input' in Entity Framework, it says no column found. Thats why I tried it with an intermediate table. And it worked.